# How to flatten an array in Photoshop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, photoshop

Here is my code :

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var allLayers = new Array;
var allLayers = collectAllLayers(doc, allLayers);

function collectAllLayers (doc, allLayers){
    for (var m = 0; m < doc.layers.length; m++){
        var theLayer = doc.layers[m];
        if (theLayer.typename === "ArtLayer"){
            allLayers.push(theLayer);
        }else{
            collectAllLayers(theLayer, allLayers);
        }
    }
    return allLayers;
}
alert("array_layers : " + allLayers);
```

I am getting in alert array like this

```
[Layer1],[Layer2],[Layer3];
```

and I want make it looks like this :

```
[Layer1,Layer2,Layer3];
```

Thanks for answers and help in advance!

Comment: Is there no way to edit bounty text? the above code examples got super ugly!

Comment: @GhoulFool this code may already be working fine. Consider how `alert([{}, {}, {}])` displays `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]`. Perhaps the question came about as a result of misunderstanding the string being displayed.

Comment: @Patrick Roberts the same I've been thinking. therefor if theLayer is an array it could be done by allLayers.push(...theLayer);

Comment: @BobWhite I doubt that Photoshop JavaScript supports spread syntax. The collections are not even arrays, which is why `reduce()` and `flat()` are not functions.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I think you are right. Ah well there goes 50 down the drain!

Comment: @GhoulFool might as well spend it on me ;)

Comment: @PatrickRoberts As easy as altruism is, don't you need an answer for that? :)

Comment: @GhoulFool why don’t you look at the answers posted below and see for yourself...

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Houston, we have a screen refresh problem...

Comment: Hi @GhoulFool! Currently, I don't have Photoshop (after Windows update) to verify my answer. But, I think `return Array.from(allLayers).flat()` could do some help. [Compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Browser_compatibility) of `Array.from()`

Comment: @rv7 `Array.from` is not a function in Photoshop JavaScript.

Comment: try it :
```
allLayers.join(',');

Answer (score 2):

The code in question already works correctly. Referring to the documentation on [`ArtLayer`](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/photoshop/pdfs/photoshop-cc-javascript-ref-2019.pdf), you can prove this by printing some of the properties for each of the objects in the array:

```
function collectAllLayers (layerSet, layers){
    for (var i = 0; i < layerSet.layers.length; i++){
        var layer = layerSet.layers[i];

        if (layer.typename === "ArtLayer"){
            layers.push(layer);
        } else {
            collectAllLayers(layer, layers);
        }
    }

    return layers;
}

function printable (artLayers) {
    var layerDescriptions = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < artLayers.length; i++) {
        var layer = artLayers[i];

        layerDescriptions.push(
            '{ name: ' + layer.name +
            ', kind: ' + layer.kind +
            ', opacity: ' + layer.opacity +
            ', visible: ' + layer.visible +
            ' }'
        );
    }

    return layerDescriptions;
}

var artLayers = collectAllLayers(app.activeDocument, []);
var layerDescriptions = printable(artLayers);

alert(layerDescriptions);
```

Answer (score 1):

Code in the question **do** display single level array of `ArtLayer` objects. One can be confused, because `toString` method of `ArtLayer` object returns name of the layer in square brackets (in version of PS that I have installed (v19.1.5), "ArtLayer" string is displayed before layer name, but still inside square brackets). For example:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
alert(doc.layers[0]); // Alerts "[ArtLayer Layer 1]"
```

[image: Alert window]

**To flatten array** `ary` you can use `[].concat.apply([], ary)`, like in:

```
var ary = [1, ["A", "B", "C"], 3];
alert(ary[2]); // Alerts "3"
alert([].concat.apply([],ary)[2]); // Alerts "B"
```

Comment: The `concat()` example is irrelevant. As you pointed out, the code in the question already generates the flat array correctly.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I agree, it's not relevant in OP's code; I decided to include it because the title of the question is "How to flatten an array in Photoshop?".

Answer (score 0):

How about using the `allLayers.push(theLayer[0]);` instead of `allLayers.push(theLayer);`.

Comment: Good try! Sadly, that just turns array layers:[Artlayer 2],[ArtLayer 1],[ArtLayer Background] into array layers:,,

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to flat the list in the recursive result?

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var allLayers = new Array;
var allLayers = collectAllLayers(doc, allLayers);

function collectAllLayers (doc, allLayers){
    for (var m = 0; m < doc.layers.length; m++){
        var theLayer = doc.layers[m];
        if (theLayer.typename === "ArtLayer"){
            allLayers.push(theLayer);
        }else{
            flatten(collectAllLayers(theLayer, allLayers));
        }
    }
    return flatten(allLayers);
}

function flatten(arr) {return arr.reduce(
  (a, b) => a.concat(Array.isArray(b) ? flatten(b) : b), []
)};

alert("array_layers : " + allLayers);
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use

```
const flatten = (layers, allLayers) => layers.reduce((acc,layer) => (Array.isArray(layer)) ? collectAllLayers(layer, acc) : acc.push(layer), allLayers);

const collectAllLayers = (doc, allLayers) => flatten(doc.layers, allLayers);
```